# React Navigation stop back button behaviour on bottom bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Hey I am using the createBottomTabNavigator() from React Navigation and I have a custom topbar which I update with my own states. The problem is when I click on a Tab the listener gets called with every navigation so the topbar gets into the wrong state if you for example go to screen 2 the topbar changes for screen 2. When I press on the topbar back button it goes back to screen 1 and changes the topbar to screen 1 topbar. Now if I use the bottombar tab instead to navigate back instead of using the topbar one it keeps the topbar from screen 2. So my question is if I can disable somehow that if I press on the bottom bar that it navigates back to the initial screen 1.

```
 <Tab.Screen
      listeners={() => {
              switchTab(0);
            }}
            name="Input"
            children={() => (
              <SuchStackContainer
                ref={suchStackRef}
                switchStack={switchStack}
                listings={listings}
                setListings={setListings}
              />
            )}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: 'Suche',
              tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
                <Ionicons name="car" color={color} size={size} />
              ),
            }}
          />
```

Comment: which navigation version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am supposing you are using [Bottom Tabs Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/) from React Navigation. As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/) you can override `onPress` method and navigate it to the desired tab. These can be specified under `screenOptions` prop of `Tab.navigator` or options prop of `Tab.Screen`. Let me know if you still need my help

```
function MyTabBar({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go somewhere"
      onPress={() => {
        // Navigate using the `navigation` prop that you received
        navigation.navigate('SomeScreen');
      }}
    />
  );
}
```